# Haar measures are decomposable

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

In the real analysis book by Folland, section $11.1$ exercise $9$ have been come that:

if $G$ is a locally compact topological group with Haar measure $\mu$, then $\mu$ is decomposable.

A measure space $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ is *decomposable* if:

> (i) $X$ is a disjoint union of measurable subsets, $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}X_{i}$, with $\mu(X_{i})<\infty$ for all $i$.

> (ii) $\mu(A)=\sum_{i\in I}\mu(A\cap X_i)$ for every measurable set $A$ of finite measure.

> (iii) if $A\subseteq X$ and $A\cap X_i\in \frak{M}$ for all $i$, then $A\in\frak{M}$.

$\textbf{EDITED:}$

$\color{red}{\textbf{I succeeded that prove (i) and (ii). }}$

$\color{red}{\textbf{can someone help me to prove (iii)? }}$

$\color{blue}{\textbf{proof of (i):}}$

if $U\subseteq G$ be a compact simetric ($U^{-1}=U$) neighbourhood of $e$ , then if $U_n=\underbrace{U...U}_{\text{n times}}$,  the sets $U_n$ for every $n$, are compact ( because action of group is countinuous) and  the set $H=\underset{n\in \mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}U_n$  is an open subgroup generated by $U$ ($H$ is open because, any set $U_n$, have a neighbourhood $U_{n+1}\subseteq H$) and we have $G=\underset{g\in C}{\bigcup}gH=\underset{\underset{n\in \mathbb{N}}{g\in C}}{\bigcup}gU_n$, where $C$  by axiom of choice is a set that contains one point from every coset $gH$. sets $gU_n$ are compact  and hence $\mu(gU_n)<\infty$.

now (i) is proved if we consider sets of the form $gU'_n=gU_n\setminus\underset{i=1}{\overset{n-1}{\bigcup}}gU_i$ instead of $gU_n$.

It causes the sets $\{gU'_n| {n\in \mathbb{N}}\}$ for every $g$, be disjoint and since $gH=\underset{n\in C}{\bigcup}gU'_n$ and the cosets $\{gH\}_{g\in C}$ are disjoint, then we have
$G=\underset{\underset{n\in \mathbb{N}}{g\in C}}{\bigcup}gU'_n$ where $\mu(gU'_n)<\infty$ and the sets $\{gU'_n|n\in \mathbb{N}, g\in C\}$ are disjoint.

$\color{blue}{\textbf{proof of (ii):}}$

if we substitute $\{gU'_n|g\in C, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ with $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$, since

$\underset{i\in F}{\sum}\mu(A\cap X_i)=\mu\Bigg(A\bigcap\bigg[\underset{i\in F}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg]\Bigg)\leq\mu(A)$

for finite set $F\subseteq I$, then

$\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(A\cap X_i )=\underset{\underset{\text{F is finite}}{F\subset I}}{\sup}\left(\underset{i\in F}{\sum}\mu(A\cap X_i)\right)\leq \mu(A)$

and hence

$$\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(A\cap X_i)\leq\mu(A) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1) $$

now if  $K\subseteq G$ be compact, then since $K\subseteq \underset{g\in C}{\bigcup}gH$ and the sets $gH$ are open, then $K\subseteq \underset{i=1}{\overset{m}{\bigcup}}g_iH$ where $g_i\in C$.

now if $\mu(A)<\infty$ and $\epsilon>0$, then by inner regularity of haar measure, there exist a compact set $K\subseteq A$ such that $\mu(A)-\epsilon<\mu(K)$. also we have

$\mu(K)=\mu\Big[K\bigcap\Bigg(\underset{i=1}{\overset{m}{\bigcup}}g_iH\Bigg)\Big]=\underset{i=1}{\overset{m}{\sum}}\mu(K\cap g_iH)=\underset{i=1}{\overset{m}{\sum}}\underset{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\sum}\mu(K\cap g_iU'_n)\leq\underset{i=1}{\overset{m}{\sum}}\underset{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\sum}\mu(A\cap g_iU'_n)\leq\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(A\cap X_i)$

then we have $\mu(A)-\epsilon<\mu(K)\leq\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(A\cap X_i)$

and since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, it follows

$$\mu(A)\leq\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(A\cap X_i) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$

and by $(1)$ and $(2)$, (ii) also is proved.